# Original Code used Int Arrays. Need to change to Vector Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, vector

TL;DR: Help me pass vector array input into a function that originally took in int pointers and ints.

I am in a college class that is learning about well-known algorithms. In this class, we use C++ to code the given algorithms. There was no pre-req class to learn C++, so my knowledge is pretty low when it comes to some of the major stuff with programming.

My problem: I have to create a program that takes an input file, sorts it with the user's choice of sorting algorithm, and write the results to an output file. My original code that works perfectly uses an input file of 20 items, placed into an array of length 20, and sorts no problem with each individual sorting algorithm.

Since last night, the only thing I have changed is that my input goes to a vector array, since the teacher will give us files of varying length (10 items to 1,000,000 items). I have four sorting algorithms that need to sort these given input files. Only one of them works, and it does not pass any variables into the function.

The other 3 originally passed in array pointers and other variables, however they do not work with my new input now going to a vector array instead of an int array. I know that what I am passing in needs to be changed, but I have no idea how to do this correctly. I have tried many different ways from sources found on the internet (with pointers and references), but I have had no luck. Here is some snipets of the code I'm using.

```
vector<int> A;

void insertionSort() // This works no problem as is.

void split(int* A, int* B, int low, int high) //code for Merge-Sort
{
    //recurisvely calls split() and splitMerge()
}

void splitMerge(int* A, int* B, int low, int mid, int high) // more code for Merge-Sort
{
    // more code for Merge-Sort
}

//quickSort() and countSort() also pass ints and do not work either.

//small part of main()
for (i = 0; unsorted >> temp; i++)
    {
        A.push_back(temp);
        cout << A[i] << "\n";
        length++; //I use int length extensively in for-loops in my functions
    }
```

Last thing. I do not get an error when trying to run the Merge-Sort. It just freezes my console window.

Answer (score 0):

conversion from vector to array is done this way

vector vInts;
...fill the vector

int * intArr=vInts[0]

so you don't need to modify your code too much

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is not enough code to make an accurate prediction on where the error may be, but I think the problem is that the sorting algorithms is doing something like A++ with you pointers to access the next member.

Because arrays store the pointer to the next array inside the object and not on adjacent cells of memory, your algorithms are cycling through stuff they shouldn't.

If this is the case, the solution to your problem is to use an iterator instead of a pointer.

```
void split(A.begin(), B.begin(), int low, int high)
```